# Magento Localhost only homepage is working

Tags: magento, hyperlink, localhost

I have downloaded my website files and db from the live server to XAMPP.
I replaced the db details and the urls in config_core_data.
Also, mod_rewrite is on.
ONLY homepage is working.

The products links and admin as well link to my live websites links.
Here is my .htaccess file

```
# All explanations you could find in .htaccess.sample file
  DirectoryIndex index.php
 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value memory_limit 768M
 php_value max_execution_time 18000
 php_flag session.auto_start off
 php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_php7.c>
 php_value memory_limit 768M
 php_value max_execution_time 18000
 php_flag session.auto_start off
 php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_security.c>
 SecFilterEngine Off
 SecFilterScanPOST Off
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset Off
AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html A0
ExpiresByType text/plain A0
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 403 /\.git
<Files composer.json>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files composer.lock>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .gitignore>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess.sample>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .php_cs>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .travis.yml>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files CHANGELOG.md>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files COPYING.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files Gruntfile.js>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files LICENSE.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files nginx.conf.sample>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files package.json>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files php.ini.sample>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files README.md>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files magento_umask>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
 ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
  ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
<FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>
```

I have tried even replacing the .htaccess with a new one, it doesn't work.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cache?

Comment: Yes, I deleted everything in var/cache but now it got worse. The admin shows the XAMPP dashboard and my products are messed up now. When I go inside a product, I don't see the pictures or the details...It really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we take anything from live to local machine & testing in local :-
1) We should use only plain .htaccess (means default one) not the live one.
2) In core_config_data table we need to replace 2 urls secure & unsecure
3) In local.xml please make sure DB name, Host, DB Username & DB Passwords all are correct. In Host, use only - localhost
4) Delete var folder itself.
5) Check the file permissions

Also please check whether there is a use of CDN. If live site is using CDN then in local pc please try changing the value of media urls, skin urls & js in System -> Configuration -> General -> Web to simple ones like this :

In Unsecure media url - {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
In Secure media url - {{secure_base_url}}media/

Please check var/log folder in exception.log & system.log
Please try to resolve that if possible.
If still not getting any idea then try disabling custom modules one by one & check if frontend is working fine or not.

Also make sure you must have these things in default .htaccess you use :
php_value memory_limit 768M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

Thank you.